# Create SQL Server trigger before insert/update

Tags: sql-server, oracle, trigger

I have a table with columns (a, b, c, d) and I would like to ensure that the 4-uplet a,b,c,d is unique for each row of the table by using SQL server triggers.

I basically would like to know how I can use triggers to check that the data that is about to be inserted/updated will not break the property I mentionned above.

So in case of an insert attempt, I would like to execute a SELECT on the table to check if the 4-uplet that's about to be inserted already exist and return an error value in this case. I would like to act similarly for updates.

**EDIT**: Actually my starting point is that I have an oracle SQL index that I want to convert to SQL Server in the context of a database migration. The Oracle SQL index creation structure is as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MY_SCHEMA.MY_UNIQUE_INDEX ON MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
(
    CASE "X_ID" WHEN 2 THEN "COL_A" ELSE NULL END ,
    CASE "X_ID" WHEN 2 THEN "COL_B" ELSE NULL END ,
    CASE "X_ID" WHEN 2 THEN "COL_C" ELSE NULL END ,
    CASE "X_ID" WHEN 2 THEN "COL_D" ELSE NULL END 
);
```

This index seems to impose unicity of (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d) 4-uplet that's why I chose to translate it by an SQL Server trigger because functional indexes don't exist in SQL Server.

Comment: Why a trigger if you want to return an error?, you should just create a unique index

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using a unique index? `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueIndexesAreEasy ON dbo.SomeTable (a,b,c,d);`

Comment: @AMtwo Please check my last edit, if a unique index can do want I describe in the EDIT why not

Comment: @kikus I assume that in your Oracle function-based index those four lines should be A,B,C,D? Not A,B,B,C?

Comment: Yes, It was just a typo

Comment: When X_ID = 2, then A,B,C,D should be unique. When X_ID <> 2, then no uniqueness is necessary. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's indeed what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: I think the index is equivalent to a unique partial index: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_a_b_c_d_when_x_id_equals_2 ON dbo.mytable (a,b,c,d) WHERE (x_id = 2);`

Comment: @RDFozz yeah, an ypercube's comment gives op the answer to his/her question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in comments, I've restated your requirements:

> When X_ID = 2, then A,B,C,D should be unique. When X_ID <> 2, then no
>   uniqueness is necessary.

You can use a filtered index in SQL Server (ie, an index with a `WHERE` clause).

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (X_ID INT, Col_A VARCHAR(10),Col_B VARCHAR(10),Col_C VARCHAR(10),Col_D VARCHAR(10))

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyUniqueIndex ON #MyTable (Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D) WHERE X_ID = 2;

INSERT INTO #MyTable (X_ID, Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D)
--non-unique values for x_id = 1
VALUES (1,'A','A','A','A'),
       (1,'A','A','A','A'),
       (1,'A','A','A','A'),
--unique values for x_id = 2
       (2,'A','A','A','A'),
       (2,'A','B','A','A'),
       (2,'A','B','C','A'),
       (2,'A','B','C','D')

--non-unique value for x_id = 2
INSERT INTO #MyTable (X_ID, Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D)
VALUES (2,'A','A','A','A')
```

The last insert will give you an error for violating uniqueness:
    Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 17
    Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.#MyTable' with unique index 'MyUniqueIndex'. The duplicate key value is (A, A, A, A).

Depending on whether the columns are `NULL`able or not, and whether you want NULL to be included in the uniqueness check you may need your `CREATE INDEX` statement to include checks for `NULL`. In the above example, SQL Server will treat `NULL` as a discrete value (which is different than the way Oracle handles `NULL`). You may instead want to use something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyUniqueIndex ON #MyTable (Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D) 
    WHERE X_ID = 2
    AND Col_A IS NOT NULL
    AND Col_B IS NOT NULL
    AND Col_C IS NOT NULL
    AND Col_D IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Right, this is correct when the 4 columns (A, B, C, D) are not nullable. If any of them (or all) are nullable, then you need to modify the index filter: `WHERE (x_id = 2 AND col_a IS NOT NULL ... AND col_d IS NOT NULL)` for 100% equivalence with Oracle's functional index. (because SQL Server behaves differently regarding Nulls and unique indexes/constraints).

Comment: Oracle would allow two rows with: `(2, 'A',' B', 'C', NULL)`. SQL Server won't.

Comment: Ah, right. I forget Oracle treats NULLS differently. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and does this work also if my table has other columns beside col_a,col_b etc and x_id? @AMtwo

Comment: Correct. Only the columns included in the index need to be unique. The table can have whatever other non-unique columns.